# getting all subscribers key when at least one has been sent

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am trying to write a query that gives me all of the subscribers keys from the all subscribers where at least one of these keys has been sent to.

I have written the following syntax:

```
select DISTINCT(s.SubscriberKey),s.EmailAddress,se.EventDate,se.OYBAccountID from ent._Subscribers s
JOIN _Sent se on s.SubscriberID=se.SubscriberID
where s.SubscriberKey is not null and se.OYBAccountID='XXXXXX'
```

However this only gives me the instances of the key when it was sent.

So lets say i have one email address with 2 subscriber key; if i amend the query for those 2 keys it will only show me the one that has been sent to which I kind of get because i do the join with the _Sent data view.

Is there a way to tweak the syntax to achieve what i need?

Thank you, 
Giulietta

Comment: Where s.SubscriberKey is Null is moot. It they are on the All Sub List then they have an SubscribeKey. I would take that out

Comment: If they are in the All subscribers list, then it is implicit that they have been sent emails.

Answer (score 2):

If you contacts are in the All Subscribers List then they have been sent an email. Are you trying to find duplicates? To do this I would use a subquery to order them and filter on conditions where there is more than one occurrence.

eg

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey 
,EmailAddress
,EventDate
,OYBAccountID
FROM 

(
SELECT

FROM
 s.SubscriberKey
,s.EmailAddress
,se.EventDate
,se.OYBAccountID 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.EmailAddress ORDER BY  s.SubscriberKey DESC) as x
from ent._Subscribers s
JOIN _Sent se on s.SubscriberID=se.SubscriberID
where se.OYBAccountID='XXXXXX') t 

WHERE t.x = 2
```

Comment: Thank you @Data_Kid.
 I have encountered the error message: An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. 

I managed to bypass that. 

SELECT SubscriberKey ,EmailAddress ,EventDate ,OYBAccountID FROM (select s.SubscriberKey,s.EmailAddress,se.EventDate,se.OYBAccountID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.EmailAddress ORDER BY s.SubscriberKey DESC) x from ent._Subscribers s JOIN _Sent se on s.SubscriberID=se.SubscriberID where se.OYBAccountID='XXXXXX') t where t.x >1

 i still dont get the information I need.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this using the following syntax:

select top 100 percent subscriberkey, emailaddress 
from ent._Subscribers 
where emailaddress in ( 
SELECT 
EmailAddress 
FROM _Sent se 
Join ent._Subscribers s on s.subscriberid = se.subscriberid 
where se.OYBAccountID='XXXXXX' ) 
order by emailaddress